# How do I increment dates in Google Sheets with Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a scheduling app using Google Sheets and Apps Scripts.  I'm trying to figure out what code to use to increment the date one day at a time starting with a certain date. What I've tried so far is...

```
var startdate = "1/13/19";
var dt = new Date(startdate);
newSheet.getRange("C1").setValue(dt);

// increment date by 1 day
dt = new Date(dt + 86400);
newSheet.getRange("D1").setValue(dt);

// increment date by 1 day
dt = new Date(dt + 86400);
newSheet.getRange("E1").setValue(dt);
```

The values I get in C1, D1, E1 are 1/13, 1/13, 1/13. If I use 86400000 milliseconds as an increment value I get 12/31/1969 as a result.

Google's Spreadsheet service does not seem to support much in the way of date functions. There's got to be a way to do this.  Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Manipulate the date using standard `Date` instance methods. You can review these in your preferred javascript language reference. As a start, make sure your input string actually parses to a valid `Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using four digit years. For dates the unit is a day so +`1` is sufficient. The way the following runs `dt` increments as cells are stepped across to the right (normally!) so for successive dates just keep adding `1` (or `2` if you do want to skip a day):

```
function one() {
  var startdate = "1/13/2019";
  var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var dt = new Date(startdate);
dt.setDate(dt.getDate());
newSheet.getRange("C1").setValue(dt);

// increment date by 1 day
dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1);
newSheet.getRange("D1").setValue(dt);

// increment date by another 1 day
dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1);
newSheet.getRange("E1").setValue(dt);
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  That's what I needed.  Thank you!